# How do I make the Internet Explorer Javascript debugger also pause on caught exceptions?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer

I am trying to debug a "property not found" exception that is only happening in IE. The bad part is that this exception is being caught and handled and I could only figure out how to make the IE 9 debugger pause on *uncaught* exceptions (Ctrl + Shift + E).

I can't temporarily remove the relevant try-catch clause without messing up my program logic and I'd rather not have to manually operate the debugger step-by-step. **How can I easily find what line is generating my exception?**

Comment: might be better off debugging this in another browser with a better debugger (chrome, ff + firebug) ... of course the bug might not exist on other browsers

Comment: @hunter: The bug only surfaces in IE (why doesn't this surprise me?)

Comment: are you using the `debugger` command in your javascript?

Comment: Wouldn't using `debugger` still force me to manualy advance step-by-step though? I want to be able to instantly move to the next `throw`, just like I can in chrome.

Comment: The closest you are going to get with the IE JS debugger is setting a condition on your breakpoint. Hopefully that could get you closer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#_break

Comment: I'd have to see your code. You could try writing to the console, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a while I conclude that there sadly is **no easy way to force IE to halt on caught exceptions.**

By the way, I have since solved the problem that triggered this question. I was console.log-ing a XML document and unlike Chrome and FF, IE doesn't handle that well. This is particularly annoying since I was using console.log calls to help debug >_<